# Python logging in Django : Filter won't work in logger

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a logging custom `filter` class which suppose to ignore Django logs in my logger 'bucket' (I don't want to disable Django logs, just to keep them in separate log):

```
class ExcludeDjangoLogsFilter(logging.Filter):
    """ Excludes django system logs from logger """
    modules_to_exclude = (
        "daphne.server",
        "django",
        "django.db",
        "django.server"
    )

    def filter(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> bool:
        """ Filters records to exclude from a logging modules with a certain names. """
        return not record.name.startswith(self.modules_to_exclude)
```

It works just fine if I pass this filter to `handler` but It doesn't if I pass this filter to `logger`. If I use this filter within logger interpreter enters the filter's class but doesn't enter in filter method.
My logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,

    # Filters:
    "filters": {
        "info_only": {
            "()": "logger.logger_filters.InfoOnlyFilter"
        },
        "exclude_django_log": {
            "()": "logger.logger_filters.ExcludeDjangoLogsFilter"
        }
    },

    # Formatters' profiles:
    "formatters": {
        "base": {
            "format": "[{asctime}][{levelname}][{name} / {funcName}][{lineno}] {message}",
            "datefmt": "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
            "style": "{"
        },
        "info": {
            "format": "[{asctime}][{name} / {funcName}] {message}",
            "datefmt": "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
            "style": "{"
        },
        "django_sys_format": {
            "format": "[{asctime}][{levelname} | {name}] {message}",
            "datefmt": "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
            "style": "{"
        }
    },

    # handlers:
    "handlers": {
        "important_file": {
            "level": "WARNING",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "base",
            "filename": BASE_DIR / "logger/logs/important.log"
        },
        "info_file": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "info",
            "filters": ["info_only"],
            "filename": BASE_DIR / "logger/logs/events_info.log",
        },

        "django_file": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "django_sys_format",
            "filename": BASE_DIR / "logger/logs/django_sys.log"
        }
    },

    # loggers:
    "loggers": {

        "root": {
            "handlers": ["important_file", "info_file"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "filters": ["exclude_django_log"],
            "propagate": True,
        },

        "django": {
            "handlers": ["django_file"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": True
        },
    }
}
```

My goal is to remove Django `INFO` messages from my `root` logger.

Comment: What's the point of adding "django", "django.db" and "django.server" *all* to the `modules_to_exclude`, given that you're using `startswith()` to match, and all those modules would match if you just used "django" instead of all three?

Comment: Those three modules were added just for test. It won’t work even with a single “django” module in list added. I just want to know why the filter works fine in handler but won’t skip any django logs when added in logger.

Answer (score 0):

On my Django start up after, loading my .env file, i set my log level depending if DEBUG, Production or any other circumstances i run my project.

If you set to 'WARNING' (numeric 30) for example INFO (numeric 20) and less like DEBUG will be ignored.

Example:

```
    import logging

    loglevel = os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL")

    # get loglevel and format
    if loglevel == 'DEBUG':
        LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG # will return a number
        debugFormat() # set new format
    elif loglevel == 'INFO': 
        LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO 
    elif loglevel == 'ERROR': 
    <...>

    # set loglevel   
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
```

Comment: In my case I use logger “root” with level “INFO” so all logs with level INFO and higher must be logged. So there is no problems with log level. The problem is filter’s method “filter” not being triggered when logging.

Comment: "My goal is to remove Django INFO messages from my root logger." So you want only certain modules to log only INFO?

Comment: Yeah, I want to log all modules INFO logs except Django INFO logs

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the `exclude_django_log` filter to the `django` logger, so of course it didn't filter any events logged to the `django` logger.

If you add

```
"filters": ["exclude_django_log"],
```

to the configuration for "loggers": { "django": { ... } }, then things logged to the `django` logger should be excluded.

However, filters added to loggers filter *only* for that logger. So you'd need to add the same filter to loggers named "django.db", "django.template" etc. etc. However, if you add the filter to a handler and attach that to the top level logger ("django") or higher, then it will filter out all records as desired.

See [this diagram](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) for the flow of information in logging.

Comment: A don’t need to filter events going to “django” logger. I want to filter “root” logger to bypass any Django events instead. Django events has to go through its own logger and record all events in a separate file.